Can I prompt a edit review?
The Q&A I found unknown PHP code on my server. How do I de-obfuscate the code? from eight years ago has a good answer, but some of the linked articles have fallen foul of link rot/takeover by apparently unsavoury entities.
So, I suggested an edit a few days ago which has been neither accepted nor rejected yet. (The author of that answer hasn't been seen on SE for over three years.)
I linked to that Q&A in the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79237910/need-help-decoding-php-file-use-obfuscator#comment139726929_79237910 as it's relevant, but it could be unfortunate, and ironic, if someone's computer got infected with malware as a result of following links on Security.SE.
I don't have access to the review queues here, so are they very inactive, or might someone be so kind as to approve or deny my suggested edit, please?

I looked at the review but decided to skip it because I myself wasn’t too sure. I don’t think it’s a good idea to update a  link to a new one unless it is very relevant (e.g. a tool repo moved site.) You could possibly find the outdated article or whatever it is from archive.org, however.

Where links have died, or the article/page has been replaced, thus invalidating the link, replacing the link to an archived version, or to an updated page, is usually the best action to take.
I looked at your edit and approved as part of my normal Saturday morning review, and then saw this meta post. Waiting a few days can be normal, especially as we get to busy or holiday times, but I see nothing wrong with you prompting in here just in case.
